# Noise injection to the weights in MLP

Tags: machine-learning

I'm reading the book "Deep learning" of I. Goodfellow, Y. Bengio, A. Courville.
At page 242, they talk about noise added to the weights of an MLP, which behave as a regularization.

J is the least square cost function for the problem without noise, and we train an MLP (with weights W to optimize) from (x,y) the training set to a prediction yhat.

The conclusion is for small eta, the minimization of the cost function with added weight noise (with covariance eta Id) is equivalent to minimization of J with an additional regularization term:

eta E[||grad_W yhat(x)||^2]

However, I cannot understand how to obtain this conclusion from (7.32) [i.e. from the definition of the cost function for this new problem]. I tried to use a Taylor development at order 1 with respect to the weights W but I cannot get the conclusion.

Can someone know the detailed calculus to obtain this result (using the same notations)?

[I don't have enough reputation to post the picture, I hope the post is enough straightforward to understand.]